# How to pass two arguments to bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I have script to change the structure from a .txt file into a 'newusers' command readable structure, which is great for 1 file, but it means I have to edit said script everytime I need to use it with a new file. I've read about positional parameters, which I think it's what I need in this situation, but not sure how to apply that to achieve my goal.

What can I do to pass the arguments while executing the script so it works with every file without needing to edit the script further/each time?

So far my script works with **bash script.sh**, no arguments.

Code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

while IFS=: read -r userid username group; do 
        if [ "$group" = "group1" ]; then
           groupid=2020
         elif [ "$group" = "group2" ]; then
           groupid=2040
         else
           echo "Unknown group"  
         fi
         echo "$userid:password123::$groupid:$username:/home/$userid/bin/bash";
done #<  users2.txt > newusers2.txt
```

Expected result:

**bash script.sh oldfile1 newfile1**

Cheers.

Comment: The first argument is `$1`, the second argument is `$2`, etc.

Comment: I understand that much, but I fail to see how can I apply that to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't `... done <"$1" >"$2"` do it? BTW, in the "Unknown group" case, it'll re-use the group number from the previous user; is that what you want?

Comment: OMG, yes that works, with a small caveat, it only works with the .txt extension, but it's easily fixed adding said extension on the variable. I knew I was overthinking it, but I couldn't for the life of me, figure it out. Thank you so much! Yeah, the Unknown group case is intended that way for further test.

Comment: is this question answered ? please close it.